# Angular view not updating after update

Tags: angularjs

My view is not getting updated after the update. Here is my controller

```
 $scope.UpdateEmp = function () {
        var empl=$scope.Employee;
        empFactory.empUpdate.update({ EmpID: $routeParams.EmpID, empval: empl });
        $location.path('/EmpList');

    };
```

In the ideal case after the update, page has to be redirected to EmpList where the $scope.Employee will query the updated list. But the page redirect takes place even before the update and once the update is completed its not even in the empList page as seen in the URL.

Another option which i tried was keeping the redirect code within the promise method as below

```
  $scope.UpdateEmp = function () {
        var empl=$scope.Employee;
        empFactory.empUpdate.update({ EmpID: $routeParams.EmpID, empval: empl }).$promise.then(function () {
            $location.path('/EmpList');
        });


    };
```

In this case, url is seen as #/EmpList as expected but the call to update the list is not working.. Means, the below code not reaching the MVC controller to get the updated data

```
 $scope.Employees = empFactories.query(function () {
        console.log($scope.Employees);
    });
```

Can someone please help me on this one

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with a more complete example

Comment: Hi Chris, I don't have experience in creating the fiddle. but in simple terms, the prob here is, aft the update method, control has to get redirected to list page where the updated data will be queried. In my case, control is redirected even before the update and data gets populated even without the update. I m using $resource for my update

Comment: can you show us the code of `empFactory.empUpdate.update`?

Comment: Please find the response in the answer section

Comment: @chris the question was reframed a bit and posted in another post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339398/) please help

Answer (score 0):

Handle "success" callback to your factory method to solve your problem

```
empFactory.empUpdate.update(empId, employee).success(function(results){

 //Update your scope variable with return results
 $scope.Employee = results;

 //Then redirect 
 $location.path('/EmpList');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating your $scope variable after the factory method call. Make changes to your code like shown below and try. Create an example in fiddle and share for better understanding.

```
    $scope.UpdateEmp = function () {
    var empl=$scope.Employee;
    empFactory.empUpdate.update({ EmpID: $routeParams.EmpID, empval: empl }).$promise.then(function (result) {
     $scope.Employee = result;
        $location.path('/EmpList');
    });


};
```

Comment: No Raja. Employees (List Page) is in different controller. I cannot assign the result in the controller here as updateEmp method is associated with edit page.